# Create new folder with current date bat file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a new folder on my 'C' drive but every time I run it, the folder is created on my desktop. Am I putting the "C:\SQL\test" in the wrong spot or do I need to add another command? Thanks

Creates folder with todays date on Desktop:

```
mkdir %date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~7,2%
```

Location I'm trying to create a folder with todays date:

```
mkdir C:\SQL\test  %date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~7,2%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is whitespace in the path. each space is seen as a separator to cmd between commands and arguments. You therefore need to enclose it in double quotes. i.e `mkdir "C:\path with spaces"`

for almost the same reason, if you wanted the below instead:

```
"C:\SQL\test\yyyymmdd"
```

then the below commands should be `mkdir "c:\SQL\test\%%~i"`

The `%date%` environment variable is not the best option to use. Running on a different PC with different regional settings will result in the incorrect output. Incorporate some `powershell.

From `cmd`

```
@for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %i in ('PowerShell -Command "& {Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"}"') do mkdir "C:\SQL\test %i~"
```

within `batch-file`

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %%i in ('PowerShell -Command "& {Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"}"') do mkdir "C:\SQL\test %%~i"
```

PS!! you can do this in standalone `powershell` alone in a `.ps1` file:

```
$var = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"
md "c:\SQL\test\$var"
```

Comment: When I try "C:\SQL\test" or mkdir "c:\SQL\test\%%~i" it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %%i in ('PowerShell -Command "& {Get-Date -format "yyyymmdd"}"') do mkdir "C:\SQL\test\%%~i"     This worked except the date was 20200817 instead of 20200717

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
mkdir "C:\SQL\test\%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~7,2%"
```

Comment: No it never, because that is incorrect! Lets say that your `%DATE%` variable value `07/17/2020`, then `%DATE:~-4,4%` would be `2020`, `%DATE:~-10,2%` would be `07`, and `%DATE:~7,2%` would be `02`. so the result which should have read `20200717` is clearly incorrect! What you should have used, was `%date:~-7,2%` not `%date:~7,2%`.